# How to config network bridge nic?

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, fedora-22

The network files in Fedora 22 server edition looks very different compared to those in F17, where I can find [this howto](https://www.howtoforge.com/virtualization-with-kvm-on-a-fedora-17-server).

My aim is to have KVM guests to be accessible over ssh and http as if they were real physical servers.

In my `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp2s0f1` I have

```
HWADDR=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=enp2s0f1
UUID=xxx
ONBOOT=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_PRIVACY=no
```

So the question is what do I need to change, so KVM guests can be accessed as if they were real physical servers?

Comment: Do you have valid IPv4 and/or IPv6 addresses to assign to those guests?

Comment: That will be routable IPv4.

Comment: Is that a question or an answer?  If you mean "*by 'valid', do you mean non-RFC1918?*", then yes, I do (and they must be routed to you, not currently in use, etc.).

Comment: Hopefully the answer to your question? The IPv4 addresses are public =)

Comment: The guests will get public IPv4 addresses, so ssh and http can by accessed by anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your virtual switching infrastructure set up correctly, then for IPv4, set up a DHCP server to assign each of those addresses to the relevant guest. You have configured the clients to request their addresses via DHCP (`BOOTPROTO=dhcp`).

Alternatively, configure the v4 addresses into the guests statically, the method for which is unchanged since the F17 guide you link to.

```
DEVICE=enp2s0f1
BOOTPROTO=static
DNS1=AAA
GATEWAY=XXX
IPADDR=YYY
NETMASK=ZZZ
ONBOOT=yes
DNS2=BBB
```

Substituting for `XXX` etc. with appropriate values.

IPv6 is trickier, but you have not thus far answered my question about v6, so we'll leave it for now.